# Aplicativos híbridos são seguros?

Tags: apache-cordova, intel-xdk

Estou começando a querer a desenvolver aplicativos híbridos como Phonegap, Cordova ou Intel-XDK. Os aplicativos híbridos rodam em uma espécie de navegador. Eu queria saber é possível roubar os códigos feitos em aplicações híbridas. Todos sabem que qualquer um consegue ver o código fonte de um site. Logo se eu for usar conexões com banco de dados seria inválido utilizar aplicativos híbridos. (Já que é possível a pessoa roubar informações do banco de dados ou até mesmo deletar dados com estas informações de conexão).

Sei que os aplicativos híbridos utilizam JavaScript como linguagem de programação. É possível roubar estas informações depois de compiladas? Alguma ferramenta que inspeciona elemento talvez.

Comment: Uma coisa que pode ser feita pra não ter acesso ao dados de acesso a banco ou qualquer coisa que queira proteger seria você criar um webservice e então seu aplicativo apenas consumiria esse webservice deixando a regra de negócio toda no seu servidor longe de bisbilhoteiros.

Comment: Mas isto significa que é possível roubar o código depois dele ser compilado?

Comment: Se você fizer ele usando um webservice não tem como roubarem o que esta no seu servidor mas qualquer um com um pouco de conhecimento pode Inspecionar sua página e conseguir pegar o que tem dentro do javascript tranquilamente isso falando de página web mas caso faça um aplicativo para mobile usando um framework tipo phonegap ou Ionic o código la dentro estara seguro.

Comment: É um app feito em phonegap ou Ionic, é um app híbrido para mobile. Não tem como inspecionar elementos nestes apps? Se não der você respondeu minha pergunta.

Comment: O ionic ou phonegap cria um executável com seu código html dentro e isso seria a mesma coisa que uma linguagem nativa como um java da vida e sim ele protege seu código, agora se jogar o html na web ai vale tudo o que te respondi até agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende da plataforma que você irá desenvolver..

*Android -> Gera APK, que são frágeis, abrindo-os com o WinRAR ele irá mostrar todo seu código na pasta www.

*iOS -> Um pouco mais seguro, mas tem jeito de conseguir facilmente abrir arquivos .ipa (acho que é esse mesmo), com o WinRAR.

*Windows Phone -> é o mais complicado de alguém conseguir, ao compilar no Visual Studio (no PhoneGap ele gera um .xap, cujo não é universal e não se consegue facilmente publicar na loja), se copilar via PhoneGap é um pouco inseguro, se criar um projeto no Visual Studio, além dele ser universal (para Windows e Windows Phone) ele vai ficar seguro assim que tu enviar para a loja e a Microsoft colocar os certificados no pacote, assim se torna muito difícil abrir os arquivos do mesmo.

Porém deve ter meios de fazer o código ficar seguro, uma melhoria bem simples é criptografar os arquivos usando o próprio Windows.

Comment: Sério que dá para pegar o www pelo WinRAR, se isto for verdade é uma grave falha na segurança. Se isto é verdade, como fazer isto? Depois de compilado achei que não tinha como pegar o código. O que eu estava pensando era roubar o código pelo navegador do Phonegap. Não acredito que o WinRAR é capaz de fazer isto.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, ao compilar ele gera um apk, xap, etc.. Daí no PC é só ir no Explorer com o botão direito clica em abrir com o WinRAR, lá vai ter uma pasta chamada www e lá vai ter seu app inteiro, no Windows Phone isso é corrigido quando tu publica o app na Store, eles bloqueiam o arquivo para abertura.. Já no Android, qualquer APK pode ser aberto com o WinRAR.. Agora, se tu deixar o app online sem compilar é mais difícil os 'espertalhões' tentar ver seu código, porém se com roubar dados você quis dizer de login etc, daí é muito mais difícil alguém roubar dados.

Comment: Ou seja, só ficará fácil se todos os arquivos mesmo do app estarem no arquivo apk etc

Comment: Não sei se no Phonegap dá para acessar a pasta WWW, porém eu abri o arquivo .apk compilado pelo intel XDK e não consegui achar esta pasta WWW. E  tinha alguns arquivos criptografado.

Comment: Legal, vou ver o Intel XDK então, o PhoneGap dá pra ver claramente os arquivos kk, além dele praticamente te obrigar deixar o app como open source.. O Intel permite anuncios? Só que ele não suporta Windows Phone né? Mas sem problema, eu uso o Visual Studio, fica até melhor o app

Comment: Ele da suporte para o Windowns phone. Eu fiz um app no phonegap builder e realmente tem um arquivo WWW lá. Porém no Intel XDK não consegui achar esta pasta e não sei se é possível consegui-la.

Comment: baixei o Intel XDK, realmente é muito bom, hoje a noite vou passar minha aplicação para ele e ver como fica, pois no PhoneGap ele perde muito a qualidade (por isso eu estava usando o Visual Studio para Windows e Windows Phone) Além disso tem vários emuladores e extensões, valeu por falar do Intel kk já tinha ouvido falar, mas não tinha curiosidade de procurar

Comment: De boas, ele compila para Windows também. Eu gostei bastante, gostei mais ainda depois que descobri que ele é mais seguro.

Comment: O meu não está querendo criar projeto, eu crio um novo projeto ou seleciono ara importar meus arquivos ele fica carregando infinitamente :( Só porque achei ele bem interessante

Comment: Cria um tópico e manda o link para mim.

Answer (score 1):

O que pode ser feito é uma pesquisa bem rápida no google:

[Como proteger código javascript.](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=como%20proteger%20c%C3%B3digo%20javascript&es_th=1)

Não vou colocar link de resposta de outro site mas a pesquisa do google sempre vai trazer resultados esperados.

Comment: Se os aplicativos híbridos já fazem esta segurança para mim não tem por que eu pesquisar como proteger meu JavaScript. A resposta Ideal seria a mesma que você colocou no comentário. Pois a pergunta é sobre app híbridos e não como proteger o JavaScript. Você poderia editar sua resposta para se adaptar a pergunta, então eu posso colocar como resolvida.

Comment: E mesmo que não consiga ler o código compilado, tem que ver se o navegador do phonegap esconda as informações dentro do navegador (os apps do phonegap rodam em um navegador embutido no próprio código). Então teria que ver se é válido colocar informações como conexão com o banco de dados lá. (Talvez algum outro aplicativa que roube o HTML) Ainda tenho dúvidas da segurança do phonegap. Logo eu quero saber o por que é seguro.

Comment: Este tipo de pergunta não pode ser respondida simplesmente com uma pesquisa do google, pois eu pesquisei e não encontrei nenhum site falando sobre a segurança do phonegap/cordova e etc. Se você achar por favor poste.

Comment: Você me entendeu mal, não coloquei esse link como se você não tivesse pesquisado foi apenas para ter uma ideia de que existe maneiras de se fazer isso, é que se eu colocar um link de um site que tenha a resposta sem colocar a resposta me chamam a atenção ai coloquei esse link apenas como fonte de pesquisa.

Comment: A sim, agora entendi. É uma maneira de proteger o código caso alguém consiga acessar o código fonte né.